# Beginner in AJAX help needed with POST

Tags: ajax

I have the following script:

```
<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#Submitter<? echo $count; ?>").submit(function(event) {
/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();
/*clear result div*/
$("#result").html('');
/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var values = $(this).serialize();
/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.ajax({
url: "<? echo Configure::read('Burl') . $cat['sub_cat_url']; ?>",
type: "post",
data: values,
success: function(){
$("#prod_add").show();
$("#prod_add").delay(2500).animate({opacity: 0},5000);
},
error:function(){
alert("failure");
$("#result").html('there is error while submit');
}   
}); 
});
</script>
```

which works, the form is posted. But how do I get access to the post variables on the same page without refreshing? Are they stored in an JavaScript array or something?

this is my form:

```
<form method="post" id="Submitter<? echo $count; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="CartAdd" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="Productcode" value="<? echo $row['Titel']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Description" value="<? echo $row['Omschrijving']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Tumbnail" value="<? echo $row['Afbeelding']; ?>">
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Order Now" class="order_button">
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to use the POST data that I would have had if I din't use AJAX and just posted the form the old fashioned way

Comment: Where do you want to use that data? At the client (javascript)? And why? jquery.serialize() returns the serialized form data which will get posted to the server.

Comment: I want to use the tumbnail in a div (id prod_add) that displays the Productcode and Tumbnail with the text, this product is added to the cart. The div is not in the for each loop that fills the $row variable so I need the POST variable or a javascript variable that contains the post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand whats the question is, but i will give it a try:

> But how do I get access to the post variables on the same page without refreshing?

There is no concept like *POST variables* client side so i guess you mean the value of the form fields you post to the server?

Just access them by id/name:

```
var valueOfTumbnail = $('input[name="Tumbnail"]).val();
```

If you want to access the whole data which gets posted use `form.serialize()` like in your method:

```
var serializedData = $("form").serialize();
```

But i don't think that this is what you want.

**EDIT**:

Try to execute the code when the document was loaded and processed by the browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // here your code...
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want but <script>document.write (values);</script> has no data and <script>document.write ($('input[name="Tumbnail"]).val());</script> displays undefined

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function() {
     document.write (values);
});</script> has no result

Comment: Have you checked with a debugger what the value of $('input[name="Tumbnail"]) is?

Comment: When I place the Document.write (values); after the AJAX script, the values are shown. Is that normal?

Comment: should values be available at the start of the document then?

Comment: The document is available when jquery executes the $(document).ready() callback